# Check element presence in array

Tags: jquery

What is the simplest way too check is some element presence to array?

I have following code:

```
    var val = "1";
    var arr = ["1", "2"];
    if($.inArray(val, arr)) {
        console.log("I am in!")
    } else {
        console.log("I am NOT here :( ")
    }
```

but it prints **"1"** is NOT at **["1", "2"]** array! Please open my eyes - what is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$.inArray` returns index of the matched element position which can range from `0` to `(length - 1)`. So you should `>= 0` as it is the first element it will be returning the index as `0`.

```
var val = "1";
var arr = ["1", "2"];
if($.inArray(val, arr) >= 0) {
    console.log("I am in!")
} else {
    console.log("I am NOT here :( ")
}
```

Comment: Very common mistake, the name implies a boolean return value.